# Using URL to connect to webservice through Java

Tags: java, url

I am using JIRA REST api to pull the issues that were created in JIRA . when i enter this URL         [ http://example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=DEMO AND issuetype=Bug&fields=summary,priority ] 
 in the browser , i am getting the issues , which are bugs , along with the fields summary and priority . But when i try to use it in a Java Application , i am not getting the same output , i am getting all the issues that are created .My doubt is how to encode this URL in a java application . I used URLEncoder.encode(String s,String enc), but it was not that helpful in encoding the URL . Any idea on how to encode this URL , cause i am not getting the response , which i got in the Browser ??

Comment: `http://example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=DEMO ` does not look like a valid url to me.  Are you sure you do not want `http://example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql&project=DEMO `

Comment: localhost:8082/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=DEMO AND issuetype=Bug&fields=summary,priority .................. This is ma complete URL

Comment: I am talking about the query string

Comment: There query string is correct , i used the same query in JIRA to filter only the Bug issues in ma project DEMO

Answer (score 0):

Before constructing the url you have to segregate individual QueryString values and Encode those following way...

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class UrlencodeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String baseUrl="http://example.com";
        String finalUrl=baseUrl + "?a=" + encode("this is") + "&b=" + encode(":url encoding:");
        System.out.println(finalUrl);
    }

    public static String encode(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        return URLEncoder.encode(str,"UTF-8");
    }
}
```